# Text independent of screen resolution in Unity?

Tags: c#, text, resolution, unity-game-engine

I have the following code that depends on the resolution of the user's display:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(432, 525, 9000, 9000), ("Hello!"));
}
```

And of course, the location of the text changes in devices with different resolutions. How can I make the text independent of screen resolution in Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Unitys new GUI system. This allows you to design the UI in the editor. You can anchor your text label to the screen in a screen-resolution independent way, and you can configure the font size to automatically adapt to the available space inside that text label.

Comment: On the new GUI system, my text isn't adjusting properly. That's why I resorted to the code listed in my question. Check [this](http://i.imgur.com/RAXrhpu.gif?1) out. I also asked a question regarding this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500532/text-not-adjusting-properly-on-canvas)

Comment: See my comment and answer there.

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around for this problem. Idea is to assign position in percentage instead of hard coded coordinates.

1. First find out your base resolution, on which further work will
   base on. Print `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`. In my case it is
   `428 x 321`.
2. Find out the percentage of current position with
   resolution. If I consider `GUI.Label(new Rect(50, 50, 300, 300),
   ("Hello!"));`, then it'd be `50.0f/428.0f` width percentage and
   `50.0f/321.0f` height percentage.
3. Now assign position w.r.t.
   these percentages. Like, `GUI.Label(new Rect((50.0f/428.0f) *
   Screen.width, (50.0f/321.0f) * Screen.height, 300, 300),
   ("Hello!"));`