# Text not adjusting properly on Canvas?

Tags: canvas, text, unity-game-engine

I want to to achieve [this](http://www.tubechop.com/watch/7537939) effect.

Comment: This question is very vague. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Also you should mention more about the context of your question. What's the environment, what is "text" and so on.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert Question edited.

Comment: And are you holding the Shift and Alt keys?

Comment: This question is pending closing because it is *unclear what you're asking*. You should fix it by using plain English description in addition to images. It must be said that even if you do so, it may still be closed as *off-topic* or *too broad*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the Rect transform tool selected (press T while Scene view has focus). This will correctly display the bounds of your selected UI element.
Also, what you are changing in your video is the anchor mode, NOT the text alignment. You can edit that in the Text component inspector, in the Paragraph section.